# How to get the cache data from specified ChannelHandler in Netty?

Tags: java, netty

In the server,when receiving request login from every client,I will cache the data 
 using  `ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>()`in the method `channelRead`,Can I get the value of the `ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>()` by defing a public method`public synchronized static Map<String, String> getClientMap()` anywhere? And I want to define a schedule task to execute the opreation of clearing the cache whose data in the above `ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>()`,how can I do in Netty? I try many times ,but failed.
This is my code in ChannelHandler：

```
public class LoginAuthRespHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginAuthRespHandler.class);

private static final Map<String, String> nodeCheck = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

private String[] whiteList = { "127.0.0.1", "192.168.56.1" };


@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    AlarmMessage message = (AlarmMessage) msg;
    //judge the messsge's type
    if (message.getHeader() != null && message.getHeader().getType() == MessageType.LOGIN_REQ.value()) {
        String nodeIndex = ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString();
        AlarmMessage loginResp = null;

        if (nodeCheck.containsKey(nodeIndex)) {
            loginResp = buildResponse(ResultType.FAIL);
        } else {
            InetSocketAddress address = (InetSocketAddress) ctx.channel().remoteAddress();
            String ip = address.getAddress().getHostAddress();
            boolean isOK = false;
            for (String WIP : whiteList) {
                if (WIP.equals(ip)) {
                    isOK = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            loginResp = isOK ? buildResponse(ResultType.SUCCESS) : buildResponse(ResultType.FAIL);
            if (isOK)
                //add a value
                nodeCheck.put(nodeIndex, message.getBody().toString());
                System.out.println(nodeCheck.get(nodeIndex));
        }

        ctx.writeAndFlush(loginResp);
    } else {
        ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
    }
}

private AlarmMessage buildResponse(ResultType result) {
    AlarmMessage message = new AlarmMessage();
    Header header = new Header();
    header.setType(MessageType.LOGIN_RESP.value());
    message.setHeader(header);
    message.setBody(result.value());
    return message;
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    String nodeIndex = ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString();
    ctx.close();
    if(nodeCheck.containsKey(nodeIndex)){
        nodeCheck.remove(nodeIndex);
    }
}

public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
    ctx.fireExceptionCaught(cause);
}
public static Map<String, String> getNodeCheck() {
    return nodeCheck;
}
```

}

And this is my code in main thread:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> sf = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            HashSet<String> clients = new HashSet<>();
            Map<String,String> map = LoginAuthRespHandler.getNodeCheck();
            System.out.println(map.size());

            for (String key:map.keySet()) {

                clients.add(map.get(key));
            }
            //update data
            try{

                MySQLDB.updateClientStatus(clients);

            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //clear map
            map.clear();
            clients.clear();
        }
    },10,10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: You don't need a `static synchronized` method to be able to safely take a snapshot of a ConcurrentHashMap or otherwise iterate it - they provide weakly consistent iterators that do not throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if that is what you are worried about. See [java.util.concurrent section "Concurrent Collections"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). Locking an external lock (static or otherwise) would only help if you also lock it on all modifications, in which case `ConcurrentHashMap` offers no advantage any more.

Comment: That said, it might be a good idea to consider using an existing cache implementation from a 3rd party library instead of rolling your own. I like [guava `CacheBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), but there are others. If you are already using a framework such as Spring, they also have a built-in solution for that.

Comment: In fact,my trouble is that a client  connects the server,the schedule task can get the value of the cache.And I test that the `ConcurrentHashMap` indeed has a value.However, the second  and later schedule tasks can't get the value of the cache.Can you help me.It make me confused many days.

Comment: Do you have some cleanup-task that periodically clears the map? Is it possible that this removes your entry?

Comment: No,I have already correct this mistake,but it does't work.

Comment: I add some code by editing my question.Please see them!